# html2cavas renders almost invisible image

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

html2canvas renders very pale images (except icons).
It seems to be rendering png icons correctly but everything else is almost invisible.
Original html:

[image]

html2canvas:

[image: html2canvas image]

and the code:

```
$("#2canvas-btn").click(function() {

let delay = 1000;

window.scrollTo(0, 0);

setTimeout(function() {

html2canvas(document.querySelector(".results-page")).then(canvas => {
document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});

}, delay);
```

});